# How to find the absolute minimum/maximum of this function over the unit ball?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am confused by this exercise.
Fin the absolute minimum and absolute maximum (if they exist) of the function
$$
f(x, y) = \log(4- x^2- y^2)
$$
on the unit ball by using a parametrization.

The domain of the function is $x^2 + y^2 <4$. The Weierstrass theorem guarantees that a minimum (or a maximum) exists.
By using the standard parametrization of the unit ball
$$
\begin{cases}
x =\cos\theta\\
y=\sin\theta
\end{cases}
$$
we have
$$F(\theta) = f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) = \log (4 -\cos^2\theta -\sin^2\theta) = \log (3).$$

It seems to me a little bit strange that we obtain a constant.

Could anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? How to proceed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your answer is constant because $x^2+y^2$ is constant (and equals $1$) on the surface of the unit ball. But the unit ball (as opposed to the unit sphere) contains its interior as well, so you have to take that into account. (Also, the question should state that this is the _closed_ unit ball. Otherwise the maximum doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit ball is $\{(r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta): 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 0\leq r \leq 1\}$. In this domain $f(x,y)=\log (4-r^{2})$. Logarithm is an increasing function so $f$ varies from $\log \, 3$ to $\log \, 4$   So, the  minimum is  $\log \, 3$ and the maximum is $\log \, 4$.

Comment: I edited a little bit to follow the usual standards of $LaTeX$. Feel free to roll back my edits

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks for editing. I was thinking of making the change myself.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for the answer. If I consider $f(r) = \log(4-r^2)$, if I compute the first derivative $f^{\prime}(r) =\frac{-2r}{4-r^2}$, it is $0$ if and only if $r=0$ which corresponds to the point $(0, \log(4))$. How to obtain the point you mentioned above, I mean $log3$ just searching critical points?

Comment: You don't always have to use derivatives. For monotone functions maximum and minimum can be written down immediately. @C.Bishop